# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<CartProduct>>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

Am having this error which worked well in android studio now I moved to vscode and is giving me the error in the title of this thread. Please find the code below.

cartProduct.dart

```
class CartProduct {
  double? totalPrice;
  String? userId;
  int? quantity;
  double? subtotal;
  String? id;
  ProductData? products;
  int? status;
  DateTime? date;

  CartProduct({
    //@required this.totalPrice,
    this.products,
    this.quantity,
    this.date,
    this.userId,
    this.id,
    this.subtotal,
    this.status,
  });
  CartProduct.fromDoucment(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    try {
      date = document.data()!['date'].cast<DateTime>();
      id = document.data()!['id'].toString();
      products = ProductData.fromMap(
          document.data()!['products']); // Here is where my issue is
      quantity = document.data()!['quantity'].cast<int>();
      subtotal = document.data()!['subtotal'].cast<double>();
      userId = document.data()!['userId'].toString();
      status = document.data()!['status'].cast<int>();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is PlatformException) {
        print('error');
      }
    }
  }
```

CartServices.dart

```
  Future<List<CartProduct>> getCartProducts(String userId) async {
    var query;
    try {

      //QuerySnapshot query;
       query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('cart').where('status', isEqualTo: 1).get();
     // if (query.docs.isNotEmpty)
        return query.docs.map((doc) => CartProduct.fromDoucment(doc)).toList();

   
    } catch (e) {
      print('error machine');
      return query.docs.map((doc) => CartProduct.fromDoucment(doc)).toList();
    }
  }
```

Am getting this error:  type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>'

Database Structure
[image]

ProductData.dart

```
class ProductData {
  String? category;
  String? description;
  String? id;
  String? images;
  String? name;
  double? price;

  ProductData({
    this.category,
    this.description,
    this.id,
    this.images,
    this.name,
    this.price,
  });

  ProductData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    id = documentSnapshot.data()!['id'];
    category = documentSnapshot.data()!['category'];
    description = documentSnapshot.data()!['description'];
    images = documentSnapshot.data()!['images'];
    name = documentSnapshot.data()!['name'];
    price = documentSnapshot.data()!['price'] + .0;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "category": category,
        "description": description,
        "images": images,
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
      };
  Map<String, dynamic> toResumeMap() {
    return {
      "id": id,
      "category": category,
      "description": description,
      "images": images,
      "name": name,
      "price": price,
    };
  }

  factory ProductData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductData(
        id: json["id"].toString(),
        category: json["category"].toString(),
        description: json["description"].toString(),
        images: json["images"].toString(),
        name: json["name"].toString(),
        price: json["price"].toDouble() + 0.0,
      );
}
```

Comment: use libraries to convert class so you can get data from firebase 

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#setting-up-json_serializable-in-a-project

Comment: You commented in your code that the issue is in this line: `products = ProductData.fromMap(document.data()!['products']);`, so can you share the `ProductData.fromMap()` code? Also, it would be helpful to see your Firestore structure.

Comment: I see that you shared the firestore structure but not the `ProductData` class, can you share that also?

Comment: @RafaelLemos thanks for you attention I have done now. thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

if you use `try catch`, you must return the values in both `try` and `catch` blocks.

Comment: I understand that and thx for the feedback. However, my issue is on the cast the data comming from firestore. 
Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the issue, I had to cast the data to the type of the method there I was receiving it from below is the solution.

```
 Future<List<CartProduct>> getCartProducts(String userId) async {
    var query;
    try {
      //QuerySnapshot query;
      query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection('cart')
          .where('status', isEqualTo: 1)
          .get();
      // if (query.docs.isNotEmpty)
      return query.docs
          .map<CartProduct>((doc) => CartProduct.fromDocument(doc))
          .toList();
    } catch (err) {
      print('Caught error: $err');
      return query.docs
          .map<CartProduct>((doc) => CartProduct.fromDocument(doc))
          .toList();
    }
  }
```